# ajax throwing error with right outcome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following function:

```
side= 'car';

    var request_checkUrl = '/antibot/antibot_data?script=' + side;

 $.ajax({
    url: request_checkUrl,
    dataType: 'application/json',
    complete: function(data){
       alert("running..");
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("ERROR");
        console.log(data);
    }

})
```

the results are:
the box with ERROR, and the running. it also shows this in the console log:

[image]

[image]

tthe response is correct. but, why does this  piece of code throw me error message, when it should be success?

I also tried with get, getjson, ajax with datatype json, etc.. but i get the same outcome.

What have i done wrong here?

EDIT:

here is the full response:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "text": "en TV",
        "images": [
            {
                "hash": "47a32df0c4b1f0b522e5faf35a46aacd95fe0ed4",
                "file": "ABImage_plane_1"
            },
            {
                "hash": "e11f83f4411364546329c8a8bf88da0dffd27029",
                "file": "ABImage_house_2"
            },
            {
                "hash": "93b4454ac09e7d7478fa2d25322e0e784370ea7a",
                "file": "ABImage_car_5"
            },
            {
                "hash": "36fac21a830b922edb507487d833556aeb9688f7",
                "file": "ABImage_clock_4"
            },
            {
                "hash": "cd1df47e052a5d0d50dab61b3e716339be0c6e68",
                "file": "ABImage_TV_3"
            },
            {
                "hash": "59e7f70b7874a500e576e25077adf254c52f5ee8",
                "file": "ABImage_train_4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

EDIT2:

this is the function that im using server sided PHP

```
echo $this->framework->ajaxJSONResponse(200, $data);
```

and

```
 function ajaxJSONResponse($status, $data)    {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        $response             = array();
        $response['status']   = $status;
        $response['data']     = $data;
        return json_encode($response);
    }
```

EDIT:
im using jquery 2.1.3

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT:
I also tried:

```
$.ajax({
    url: request_checkUrl,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json", // "xml", "json"
    success: function (data) {

        alert("success");
        alert(data);

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
        alert(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

with the output error:

[image]

UPDATE AGAIN:

i tried to validate url with:
http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

and got:

```
The JSON input is NOT valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specification). Unexpected token {"status":200,"data":{"text":"en TV","images":[{"hash":"47a32df0c4b1f0b522e5faf35a46aacd95fe0ed4","file":"ABImage_plane_1"},...
```

but if i enable:

> Accept non-quoted names

i get :

```
The JSON input is valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specfication).
```

how can i make this work on my request too?

Comment: Because the output is not valid JSON

Comment: hmm. what is wrong with it? and how can i make it work?

Comment: make sure you're returning  "application/json" as the Content-Type header from your script.

Comment: @lansen im returning that yes.

Comment: The edit shows valid JSON, the image doesn't. are you *certain* that's what you get?

Comment: yeah. i get that. let me edit again.

Comment: 1. I'm pretty sure `'application/json'` isn't a valid `dataType`, use `'json'` or better yet remove completely (for now). 2. The error function accepts 3 arguments, the last being an error message. use that.

Comment: Change dataType: 'application/json' to dataType: 'json'.

Comment: Try adding «type: "GET",» in your $.ajax({}) function.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez same result :/

Comment: @maria Please, check my answer and let me know if this works.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez tried it. and wont work :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92060/discussion-between-danny-fardy-jhonston-bermudez-and-maria).

Answer (score 0):

The following answer just try to help with a possible solution.

Try to fix your code to something like this:

```
var side = 'car';
var request_checkUrl = '/antibot/antibot_data?script=' + side;

$.ajax({
    url: request_checkUrl,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
        document.title = "Running...";
    },
    success: function (data) {
        document.title = "Success.";
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("ERROR");
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Let me know if this works.

**Update:**

In your last update, you are getting an invalid json. Since PHP you need to print a valid json, always. You might use this link to validate your json output: http://pro.jsonlint.com.

`parsererror, SintaxError: Unexpected token`: It means, you've something wrong in php code.

Comment: Tried out your code. still error. and still same output.

Comment: What jQuery version are you using in this project? Can you update your question with the complete section where you are calling to the ajaxJSONResponse function in PHP?

Comment: I validated the json on the link. no errors from that side.

Comment: As you're working with $.ajax() function, you should validate your json response with: http://pro.jsonlint.com/. This is a standard tool. However, the problem is from your ajaxJSONResponse function in PHP.

You must to try printing a very simple json from your php code.

Comment: You must to try printing a very simple json from your php code in order to get $.ajax working in the web page. Testing responses.

Comment: could we discuss this over chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92082/discussion-between-danny-fardy-jhonston-bermudez-and-maria).