# Ajax request always get error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

Actually i'm using CodeIgniter as backend in my project and jQuery 2.1.3 in my frontend.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When i run this function:

```
var side = 'biltyveri';
var request_checkUrl = '/antibot/antibot_data?script=' + side;

$.ajax({
    url: request_checkUrl,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
        document.title = "Running...";
    },
    success: function (data) {
        document.title = "Success.";
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("ERROR");
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Always displays ERROR and never displays the success function. I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

In my Controller i'm running this code:

```
echo $this->framework->ajaxJSONResponse(200, $data);
```

And this is the function it gives a response json:

```
function ajaxJSONResponse($status, $data) {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $response             = array();
    $response['status']   = $status;
    $response['data']     = $data;
    return json_encode($response);
}
```

The code above give a json response as follows:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "text": "en TV",
        "images": [
            {
                "hash": "47a32df0c4b1f0b522e5faf35a46aacd95fe0ed4",
                "file": "ABImage_plane_1"
            },
            {
                "hash": "e11f83f4411364546329c8a8bf88da0dffd27029",
                "file": "ABImage_house_2"
            },
            {
                "hash": "93b4454ac09e7d7478fa2d25322e0e784370ea7a",
                "file": "ABImage_car_5"
            },
            {
                "hash": "36fac21a830b922edb507487d833556aeb9688f7",
                "file": "ABImage_clock_4"
            },
            {
                "hash": "cd1df47e052a5d0d50dab61b3e716339be0c6e68",
                "file": "ABImage_TV_3"
            },
            {
                "hash": "59e7f70b7874a500e576e25077adf254c52f5ee8",
                "file": "ABImage_train_4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:
route:

```
$route['antibot/antibot_data'] = "antibot/antibot_interface_controller/antibot_data";
```

Background: [ajax throwing error with right outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069713/ajax-throwing-error-with-right-outcome/33070574)

Comment: Have you check your developer tools to see the request status and ensure the type is actually being set as json properly? The only reason $.ajax should fail on a successful request is if the json isn't valid.

Comment: [Read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) especially the bit about when the error function is called. It would seem the request cannot be made. Error is passed more than argument when called. Log them all and go from there.

Comment: Remove `beforeSend`  in ajax and paste `document.title = "Running...";` before `url:`

Comment: Are you passsing any data to ajax?? If yes i cant find that in your code

Comment: It seems the use of `$.ajax()` and coresponding HTTP request are to blame as the PHP seems fine.
Please provide the value of `data` being passed to your error callback and both request and response headers sent and received to/from your browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you using Codeigniter, Your **URL is wrong**

```
var side = 'biltyveri';
var request_checkUrl = '/antibot/antibot_data?script=' + side;
```

This should come as

```
url: "<?php echo base_url()?>Controller_name/method_name",
```

and method should be `post`

```
type: "POST",
```

and pass data with

```
data : {"script : side, someOther: anotherValue"}
```

in controller method, Use this

```
$script = $_POST['script'];
$someOther = $_POST['anotherValue'];
```

Comment: Its already set in the router`s file so i get the response there as i should.